# Split stings using REGEX in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, split

I'm trying to parse string into 5 parts. For example:

```
var str1 = '#<SYSTEM list-of / asdf-finalizers-20140826-git / quicklisp 2014-08-26>'

// filter is used to remove empty strings from the returned array
str1.split(/[ #<>/]/).filter(function(n) { return n !== ''; });

// str1[0] -> SYSTEM
// str1[1] -> list-of
// str1[2] -> asdf-finalizers-20140826-git
// str2[3] -> quicklisp
// str2[3] -> 2014-08-26
```

But the problem is, I can't parse the strings containing slash in the middle of words For example,

`#<SYSTEM asdf-finalizers-test/1 / asdf-finalizers-20140826-git / quicklisp 2014-08-26>`

What is the correct regex to parse the word `asdf-finalizers-test/1`? I tried these but failed.

`/[(\s\/\s) #<>]/`, `/[(?:\s\/\s) #<>]/`, `/[ #<>]|(\s\/\s)/`

Comment: If slashes must have spaces on either side to function as separators, then use `/[ #<>]| \/ ]/`. Your filter can also be written as `filter(Boolean)`.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks. `filter(Boolean)` is so handy. But `/[ #<>]| \/ ]/` doesn't work. I'm using `node.js 0.10.31` It is because of `nodejs`?

Comment: Swap the two options, so `/ \/ |[ #<>]/`. Works in both browser and node. The problem is that if the ` / ` option is placed second, it matches on the space first before it gets to the second option, and you end up with slashes in your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to not to split according to `/` when it is followed by a word character.

```
> var s = "#<SYSTEM asdf-finalizers-test/1 / asdf-finalizers-20140826-git / quicklisp 2014-08-26>"
> s.split(/[ #<>]|\/(?!\w)/).filter(function(n) { return n !== ''; });
[ 'SYSTEM',
  'asdf-finalizers-test/1',
  'asdf-finalizers-20140826-git',
  'quicklisp',
  '2014-08-26' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work:

```
/ \/ |[ #<>]/

'#<SYSTEM asdf-finalizers-test/1 / asdf-finalizers-20140826-git / quicklisp 2014-08-26>'.split(/ \/ |[ #<>]/).filter(Boolean)
> [ 'SYSTEM',
    'asdf-finalizers-test/1',
    'asdf-finalizers-20140826-git',
    'quicklisp',
    '2014-08-26' ]
```